# What's the difference between $model->foo and $model->getAttributeValue('foo')?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

When I have an instance of Eloquent model called $model I can retrieve a value of its attribute (for example name of an user) in two ways:

```
$name = $user->name;
```

or

```
$name = $user->getAttributeValue('name');
```

Which way is correct and what is the difference between those two ways of retrieving a value?

Comment: I think most of the documentation, if not all, access attributes through properties.

Comment: I think both will work.

Comment: You can see the definition https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L325

Comment: I think it's the same. Just keep in mind that you can't use `getAttributeValue()` to get model relationships.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call a model attribute,

- First the [`__get()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/987a21f39f203c76665f6014cbef10451689fbdd/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1402) method is called.
- Then the `getAttribute()` method is called.
- And finally `getAttributeValue()` or `getRelationValue()` is called.

So, it's basically the same using a property or `getAttributeValue()` to get a model attribute. Just keep in mind that it can't access model relationships.

Let's note that most (or all?) of the Laravel documentation uses properties to access a model attributes.